# AES algorithm differs in PHP from Android and iOS

Tags: php, android, ios, aes

Hi I am currently working for encryption and decryption for a string using AES algorithm in PHP and Android. I got the similar values in iOS and in Android. But I cant get the same output in PHP. It shows some other encrypted string. I want to achieve the same result in all iOS, Android and PHP. At the moment iOS and Android are working fine. But I cant fix in PHP.

Please check the screenshots and compare the values. I used "Android" as value and "abcdef" as key.

```
<?php

$Pass = "abcdef";
$Clear = "android";        

$crypted = mc_encrypt($Clear, $Pass);
echo "Encrypred: ".$crypted."</br>";

$newClear = mc_decrypt($crypted, $Pass);
echo "Decrypred: ".$newClear."</br>";  



function mc_encrypt($encrypt, $mc_key) {
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
    $passcrypt = trim(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $mc_key, trim($encrypt), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));
    $encode = base64_encode($passcrypt);
    return $encode;
}

function mc_decrypt($decrypt, $mc_key) {
    $decoded = base64_decode($decrypt);
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
    $decrypted = trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $mc_key, trim($decoded), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));
    return $decrypted;
}

?>
```

I get the following output
Encrypred: +NzljOmN0msNkWr/cst11Q==

Decrypred: android

[image: in iPhone]

[image: in Android]

Below code is used in Android

```
package com.example.aesalg;

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import android.util.Base64;

public class AESCrypt {

private final Cipher cipher;
private final SecretKeySpec key;
private AlgorithmParameterSpec spec;


public AESCrypt(String password) throws Exception
{
    // hash password with SHA-256 and crop the output to 128-bit for key
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    digest.update(password.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    byte[] keyBytes = new byte[32];
    System.arraycopy(digest.digest(), 0, keyBytes, 0, keyBytes.length);

    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding");
    key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
    spec = getIV();
}       

public AlgorithmParameterSpec getIV()
{
    byte[] iv = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, };
    IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec;
    ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);

    return ivParameterSpec;
}

public String encrypt(String plainText) throws Exception
{
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, spec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plainText.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    String encryptedText = new String(Base64.encode(encrypted, Base64.DEFAULT), "UTF-8");
    System.out.println("Encrypt Data"+ encryptedText);
    return encryptedText;
}

public String decrypt(String cryptedText) throws Exception
{
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, spec);
    byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(cryptedText, Base64.DEFAULT);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(bytes);
    String decryptedText = new String(decrypted, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println("Encrypt Data"+ decryptedText);
    return decryptedText;
}
}
```

Comment: what is your output in  php ?

Comment: How many bits are the mobile versions? Try one of the different PHP encryption types - perhaps it is not 128 you want: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.ciphers.php

Comment: what android code is used?

Comment: Do you get the same encrypted output everytime you run your PHP / android / iOS code?

Comment: @cuewizchris Yes I get the same output everytime.

Comment: @cyberwalker +NzljOmN0msNkWr/cst11Q==

Comment: @halfer I'm not sure about the encryption type. Please check the code I used

Comment: @Tishka17 I have added the android code. Please check now.

Comment: @Dinesh can you please add IOS code also.

Answer (score 3):

You are using CBC in your Android app and ECB in the PHP code. See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) for more details.

Try to change mcrypt parameter to `MCRYPT_MODE_CBC`. Also I believe mcrypt is always using zero padding (I'm not a PHP expert) so on the Android side you have to use `"AES/CBC/ZeroBytePadding"`

Comment: Can you explain what it is in the Java code that shows this to be the case (or is it a default that needs changing)? Can you explain the difference between the two modes, and suggest which one would be best changed? (This may be the right answer, but substantial answers are encouraged here `:=)`).

Answer (score 0):

in php try this code

```
  public function encrypt($string, $key)
  {
      $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, '');
      $block = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
      $pad = $block - (strlen($string) % $block);
      $string .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
      mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, 'fedcba9876543210');
      $encrypted = mcrypt_generic($td, $string);
      mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
      mcrypt_module_close($td);

      return $encrypted;
  }

  function decrypt($string, $key) 
  {
      $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, '');
      mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, 'fedcba9876543210');
      $decrypted = mdecrypt_generic($td, $string);
      mcrypt_generic_deinit($td); 
      mcrypt_module_close($td);

      return $decrypted;
  }
```

Comment: Hello,Dinesh 
Can you share your iOS Code detail ? If it generates encrypted string same as Android , and also php code if you have got solution of your current issue.